# Android MVP How to get data back from model to presenter

Tags: android, design-patterns, model, mvp, presenter

After some time developing personal Android Applications I found that usually Activities get really big and have both logic and UI operations quite mixed up.

So looking for a way to separate logic from UI I came across MVP pattern and now I'm trying to implement it in the application I'm going to develop.

So basically this would be my approach:

[image]

The issue I'm facing now is that in order to get data back from model to presenter I'd do something like this:

```
public static ModelManager (OnePresenter presenter)
{
    localPresenter = presenter
}
```

And then:

```
public onReturnData(){
    localPresenter.returnData();
}
```

The issue is that Model Manager could be called from any presenter at any time so how could I pass a reference of a Generic Presenter?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, I do not think that your approach is the best way to handle this. You can actually just use an **observer pattern** or an **EventBus** to notify the **presenters** when the data was received. That way you can keep your **presenter** separated from the **model** .. this should make the whole architecture a little cleaner.

*But to answer your question:*

All of your separate items should not communicate directly with one another. Instead the real implementation should be hidden behind an **interface**. That means, the **view** does not know anything about the **presenter** (it doesn’t even know that a **presenter** class exists), it only knows the **interface** the exposes the calls that the **view** needs.

That way you can simply define an **interface** for the communication between the **ModelManager** and the **presenter**:

```
interface ModelToPresenterInterface {
    void returnData(Object data);
}
```

All your **presenters** need to implement this (of course):

```
public myPresenter implements ModelToPresenterInterface {
    void returnData(Object data){
        // put your business logic here
    }
}
```

With this, you can just pass the **interface** (which every one of your **presenters** has implemented) to the **ModelManager**. This should probably not happen in the constructor, since there will only be a single instance of your manager that is used by every **presenter**.

```
static class ModelManager{

    List<ModelToPresenterInterface> callbackList = new ArrayList<>();

    void addListeningPresenter(ModelToPresenterInterface presenter){
        callbackList.push(presenter);
    }

    public onReturnData(Object data){
        for (int i = 0;i<callbackList.size();++i){
            callbackList.get(i).returnData(object);
        }
    }
}
```

As long as you are sure that there is always only a single **presenter** that is interested in your data (so that there are no **presenters** further down the stack) then you can also just use a single variable that gets overwritten for each new **presenter**.

**Also be very carefull that you do remove the presenters from the list when it gets destroyed!** (if not this will create major memory leaks)

Once again: I really think you will get better results using an **EventBus** or something similar, but this version should also work. Hope I could help and let me know if you have additional questions :)

Comment: Thank you for a really valuable answer.